# Can Snap-Windows be set up for 4 windows instead of just 2?

Tags: unity, 13.04, window, snap-windows

The title might need some adjusting but what I am trying to say is that, when one drags a window to the left or right side of the screen, it resizes to fill that half of the screen. So if I drag 2 windows, one to the left and one to the right, I can have to 2 windows that use the whole screen and do not overlap. For example, for cases where I want to explain about web programming and on one window I have the code and on the other I have the web browser.

Now, what if I wanted to have 4 instead of 2. One window would resize to take the top-left, the other the top-right, then 2 more would take the bottom-left and bottom-right. All of this would take those positions if I dragged them to their respective corners (eg: The top-left window would resize to that position if I drag it to the top-left corner of the screen, the bottom-right would resize to that position if I drag it to the bottom-right corner of the screen).

So how can I add 2 more positions so Unity handles all of this 4 positions instead of only 2?

Comment: Currently is it adjusting for 4 corners or not ? Please specify.

Comment: Well there are 4 corners on a screen and as I mentioned on the question I want 4 windows, each on each corner of the screen (top-left to bottom-right).

Comment: I have tried myself now. When we drag the window to any of the left or right side, it will occupy that position. Rather it fills that space. I tried for four windows but drag and drop is not working I guess. The only option is that you can resize manually.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you can edit the EDGE settings in GRID using the CompizConfig Setting Manager
(to install this run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` in a terminal).

[image]

If you set the corner setting (i.e setting Upper Left Corner to Top Left Corner) then when you drag the windows to the corners, it will "SNAP"

Answer (score 17):

Ok found the option using Compiz (We need CompizConfig Settings Manager installed). Open CCSM and go to the **Window Management**

[image]

The plugin we will use is the **Grid** plugin. Open it and select the **Edges** tab.

[image]

Now change each behavior until they look like the image above so that:

**Upper Left Corner** - Top Left Corner

**Upper Right Corner** - Top Right Corner

**Bottom Left Corner** - Bottom Left Corner

**Bottom Right Corner** - Bottom Right Corner

Now logout of your system and log back in. This is to avoid any weird graphics effects.

Now what you have is a system where, if you drag a window to one of the corners, it will get assigned to that corner and not the half of the screen. So dragging a windows to the bottom-left will assign the window to the bottom-left grid. Dragging it to the top-right corner, will assign the window to the top-right grid and the left and right screens (Left and Right halves of the screen) will still work just by dragging the window to either the Left or Right of the screen.

The final output should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 18 uses the GNOME desktop manager instead of Unity now, so you must use GNOME extensions to get this capability instead. I've written thorough instructions on how to do it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1089033/327339.