# Can the positions for Unity Window Snapping be modified to include more options?

Tags: unity, 13.04, window-manager

There is a pre-existing question similar to mine that you can find here: [Can Snap-Windows be set up for 4 windows instead of just 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310316/can-snap-windows-be-set-up-for-4-windows-instead-of-just-2)

The questioner didn't ask the question with enough detail. In the current version of Windows Snap you can only select left or right half, top or bottom half, one of the corners, or maximize. I have a 1080p display on my laptop and would like to be able to add more options to snapping. I use some apps that take up much of the screen and other apps that require much less room.

I'd like to add the option to snap 3/4 to the left and 1/4 to the right. Is this possible?

Comment: @Rodislav that is not true. It is possible in Unity, it's just not exposed in the settings.

Comment: ok, I guess you are right, I've removed my comment to avoid bad info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. If you use CCSM, you can configure the "grid" plugin to include all the corners of the screen and even the bottom edge of the screen.

[image]

Click below to install:

[image: Install via the software center]

Then:

- Run "ccsm" from the Dash.
- Select the Grid Plugin.
- Select Edges.
- Customize to your heart's content.
- *Do not skin a puppy or perform the rain dance.*
- Profit.

#### Upon re-reading your question:

The level of precision you seek is not available. You said in a comment "without having to drag" (please don't expand the scope of your question in comments ;)) though, and this can be done with keybindings.

Comment: I already have CCSM and this functionality is available, but is limited to the available screen positions. What I would like to do is to add more positions. What I do now is snap a window, like Chrome, to the left, and then drag the right edge until it covers about 3/4's of the screen. I would like to achieve this without having to drag. The positions that are available must be defined in a configuration file somewhere? Does anyone know which file this is?